# Store data "inside" app without storing it in databases

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, models

I have the following situation: I have some models in which I deserealize data from XML (which was received by GET request). Then i want to use these objects everywhere in app. How to store them? I don't want to store this data in local databases.

P.S. I use MVVM

Comment: just write them to a file?

Comment: @Jason i think it is not really fast and reliable way to do this

Comment: well, then store them in memory.   Use a singleton or static class so you can access them throughout the app.

Comment: You can store it in app preferences

Comment: Take a look at Akavache https://github.com/akavache/Akavache. It might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your options as I see it:

1. **If you need it to persist when the app is closed**

Sqlite and store it locall. Sqlite isn't that scary if that's what you're worried about. Here's a good blog post on how to handle it in a really easy way: [Super Simple Sqlite](https://alexdunn.org/2017/02/23/xamarin-tips-super-simple-sqlite/)

Write to a file like @Jason suggested.

Use a key-value storage like @apineda suggested.

For all of these, you can use them *WITH* what I explain below.

2. **If you do not need it to persist**
   Create a `Store` that has a property for your collection of data. Then access that `Store` class from your `ViewModels` or another `Service` layer or whatever you like. This can be combined with any of the above mentioned long-term storage strategies. If you need your `Store` to persist, consider using Dependency Injection to inject it into your `ViewModels` that require it, or store it as a reference in your `App` if you're using Xamarin.Forms or some Singleton.

Here's an example:

```
public class ItemStore
{
    public List<Item> DataItems { get; set; }
}
```

Then set a store property in your `App.cs`:

```
public class App : Application
{
    ...
    public ItemStore ItemStore { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then reference it from your `ViewModel`:

```
((App)App.Current).ItemStore.DataItems = yourParsedCollection;
```

And you can get it in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your data in a file and load from here every time you want . It's really fast if a data is only one xml file.

Take a look Saving and Loading Files

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/